# Run Docker in daemon mode

Tags: docker, daemon, docker-registry

I issued this command

sudo docker daemon -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock -H tcp://xxxx:8400 -H tcp://yyyyy:2375 &

It working fine. but it not returning to my console client. it not finishing the command.

```
WARN[0000] /!\ DON'T BIND ON ANY IP ADDRESS WITHOUT setting -tlsverify IF YOU DON'T KNOW WHAT YOU'RE DOING /!\ 
WARN[0000] /!\ DON'T BIND ON ANY IP ADDRESS WITHOUT setting -tlsverify IF YOU DON'T KNOW WHAT YOU'RE DOING /!\ 
INFO[0000] [graphdriver] using prior storage driver "aufs" 
INFO[0000] Graph migration to content-addressability took 0.00 seconds 
INFO[0000] Firewalld running: false                     
INFO[0000] Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172.17.0.0/16. Daemon option --bip can be used to set a preferred IP address 
WARN[0000] Your kernel does not support swap memory limit. 
INFO[0000] Loading containers: start.                   
.
INFO[0000] Loading containers: done.                    
INFO[0000] Daemon has completed initialization          
INFO[0000] Docker daemon                                 commit=20f81dd execdriver=native-0.2 graphdriver=aufs version=1.10.3
INFO[0000] API listen on 172.31.16.21:2375              
INFO[0000] API listen on /var/run/docker.sock           
INFO[0000] API listen on 172.31.16.21:8400
```

this time I can access it from out side client. but if kill that console. I cannot access it from out side client.

any solution for this?

don't know why docker becoming so complex for the beginners :)

Comment: try adding -d to the command

Comment: please note it not just docker , it is docker daemon .

if try , it gives -> flag provided but not defined: -d

Answer (score 3):

Before I say anything else, I need to warn you against running the Docker daemon like this, listening for TCP connections instead of Unix file socket connections. You probably won't listen to me, but when you get some time, you should read the warnings in the documentation I am about to link, because it's dangerous. So, anyways... You are running a docker daemon when you should be changing your initialization options for docker. [The documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/daemon/#daemon-configuration-file) details for you which file you should edit in order to change the configuration for the Docker daemon. **Be advised that duplicate options in your run command and in the config file will mean that the daemon will not start.** So if you change your `daemon.json` file and also try to run the daemon with those command line options, your server will ignore them both. The file to edit is `/etc/docker/daemon.json`, and you should set those options in there like this:

```
{
  hosts: [
    'unix:///var/run/docker.sock',
    'tcp://xxxx:8400',
    'tcp://yyyyy:2375'
  ]
}
```

Once you have edited that file, you now should restart your docker daemon:

```
sudo service docker restart
```

Or if you're using systemd:

```
sudo systemctl restart docker.service
```

Also the central problem you are experiencing has to do with running a daemon process inside of a terminal. In the future, look at the `nohup` command for running a process inside your terminal and keeping it alive after you close the terminal. You can read more at `man nohup`.

Comment: thank you , I will try this. I am beginner to docker :) so dont know what is the correct way to do it. I will follow this now.

Comment: does't work, after adding this file, my daemon not starting. any idea how to fix?

Comment: Documentation link update: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#daemon-configuration-file