# How to start docker daemon automatically with custom arguments in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, docker, phpstorm

I need to start docker daemon with some command line arguments in Ubuntu, and when doing so manually, the following command works fine:

```
$ dockerd -H fd:// -H tcp://127.0.0.1:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock
```

The above command makes it possible for me to integrate docker with PhpStorm's docker plugin, and configure containers from there. Docker daemon starts listening to TCP port 2375 that is used by PhpStorm in my case.

I need to start docker daemon automatically with the same parameters, and it seems that there is a lot of controversial information about it. I tried many different solutions, including changing `/etc/default/docker` or `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/docker.conf` and editing `DOCKER_OPTS` parameter there.

How can I run docker daemon with the above command line arguments automatically in Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: I needed >sudo service docker restart On Ubuntu 16.04 the suggested >systemctl daemon-reload did not help. Otherwise I used the Another solution from Yury Fedorow's answer. However I added an insecure registry, not a port to listen on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Among other solutions that didn't work, [here](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/9889) is one that did work. It includes changing the `docker.service` definition:

```
# edit the following file
# /lib/systemd/system/docker.service
# ...
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// -H tcp://127.0.0.1:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock
# ...
```

After changing that file, run `systemctl daemon-reload` to apply the changes made to `docker.service` file, followed by `service docker restart`.

[Another solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35969721/run-docker-in-daemon-mode) does not require changes to `docker.service` file, which can be later replaced after upgrading docker package, breaking the configuration. It requires creating or editing of `/etc/docker/daemon.json` file:

```
{
  "hosts": [
    "fd://",
    "unix:///var/run/docker.sock",
    "tcp://127.0.0.1:2375"
  ]
}
```

Restarting docker service after these changes are made also makes docker daemon listen to TCP connections on port 2375 or connections using Unix socket.

Note that the above solutions cannot be used together: **only one of them should be used** to prevent conflicts.

Comment: I had to use the same workaround using docker.service, unfortunately, official way of using DOCKER_OPTS ignores this particular setting.